# DateTimePicker how to trigger onChangeTime() from outside the constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I created a DateTimePicker and am currently using the "onChangeDateTime" as a means of updating a page using ajax.  But I'm not a front end person and I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is going on and I have almost no experience with Jquery.  I'm working on learning more but in the mean time I'd appreciate some advice if anyone is offering.

What I'm trying to do is have a link/button on the page where I can call some method to change the time in the date picker and have it trigger the onChangeDateTime function.

I thought it would be as simple as doing $("#DateTimePicker").somefunction() to change the time but I can't seem to figure out even how to change the time nor how to trigger onChangeDateTime().

I'm creating a schedule viewer and I'd like to let users click a button to cycle forward and backward in time rather than having to select the specific time over and over again on the datetimepicker.

I got my version of datepicker from http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Edit: this is what I've written so far.

```
 <body>
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" value="2015/04/08 17:49">

    <a id="myLink" title="Click to do something"
    href="#" onclick="backEpisodes();">Backwards</a>

    <a id="myLink" title="Click to do something"
    href="#" onclick="forwardEpisodes();">Forwards</a>

 <script>
 jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        formatTime:'g:ia',
        format: 'm/d/Y g:i a',
        inline:true,
        maxDate:'<?php echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime("+3 week")); ?>',
        onSelectTime:function(current_time,$input){
            updateEp($input.val());
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Without any code examples you're going to get very generic answers - like copy & paste from the documentation

Comment: Does $('#DateTimePicker').data('xdsoft_datetime').setCurrentTime(this.value); work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically set the value of the DateTimePicker by using it's `setOptions()` function and specifying the "value" option like this:

```
$('datetimepicker').data('xdsoft_datetimepicker').setOptions({
    value: '1944/06/06 6:06' // Of course this needs to match the correct format
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z37bdutx/)

Note: The jsfiddle contains a function that parses a string into a JavaScript `Date` object. That could be implemented using a regular expression, but I took a shortcut and utilized the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library.

---

Notes:

- You might want to use the "onChangeDateTime" option, rather than the "onSelectTime" option if you want that code to also execute when the user changes the date.
- The format of your initial value ("2015/04/08 17:49") does not match the format you give to the datetimepicker ('m/d/Y g:i a'). You will want to correct that.
- The "formatTime" option is needed only if you are specifying the "minTime" and/or "maxTime" options. Similarly, the "formatDate" option is needed only if you are specifying the "minDate" and/or "maxDate" options. Therefore, you don't need to specify the "formatTime" option. You could specify the "formatDate" option since you do specify a "maxDate", but it defaults to "Y/m/d".
- `id` values should be unique, so you should not use "myLink" as the value for both your `<a>` elements.

Comment: I suppose if I create a secondary variable that is updated via "onSetTime" I could do that.  I'd rather update the date picker some how so that people can see what "d/m/Y g:i A" they are looking at though.  I suppose I could have it output that at the top of the screen as well.

Comment: @FredMan - Is the DateTimePicker open (displayed) while the user clicks the button?

Comment: @FredMan - Also, what I show in my answer is just an example. I realize you are dealing with time values for your scheduler.

Comment: Yes, it is set to always stay open right now.  (Also I edited my original post to show the javascript I'm using right now for the datetimepicker)  I think you're idea will work if I just have an independent variable and update around that whenever doing backward/forward selections.